# How to use your own router with externally available Wi-Fi? (smart home, wireless printing etc.)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

I have a WiFi password for my neighbor's router. I can access the internet on any device.

However, my IKEA Tradfri gateway needs to be connected to a router using an Ethernet cable. I can't use my neighbor's router for that.

I also have a router (from my old internet provider) that I am not currently using.

Is it possible to configure my old router so that it connects to my neighbor's router using the password, then "redistributes" the internet access in my home? That way I could physically connect my Tradfri gateway to my own router, have the ability to control the lights in my home using an app and still have Internet access.

Is this possible?

(I have a feeling that this question has been asked before, but in different words. What should I google?)

Comment: What you want is a repeater/bridge and yes, it's possible if that feature is available in your router.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether our router supports wireless bridging. If this function is supported, after the bridging is successful, our router is equivalent to a wireless-enabled switch, it can be connected to the neighboring router wirelessly, and then the LAN port of our router can obtain the IP address of the neighboring router.

We can refer to the part **What Does a Wireless Bridge Do?** in the following article.
https://pcdreams.com.sg/whats-the-difference-between-a-wireless-repeater-and-a-wireless-bridge/